# How do I get the application name from within a dll?

Tags: windows, dll

If I had a dll (foo.dll) that was LoadLibrary'd into an application (bar.exe), how do I get the string "bar.exe" from within foo.dll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass NULL as the first parameter to [GetModuleFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197(VS.85).aspx).